# How to determine if characters within a file have been corrupted or are just being viewed with incorrect encoding

Tags: character-encoding, ascii

The file I'm dealing with contains text where some characters aren't showing correctly upon opening.

I've been told the file has UTF-8 encoding but when I open in sublime text 3 (I even used the re-open in UTF-8 option) there are a number of characters that show as `?` -
 For example `Jiří` is incorrectly being shown as `Ji?í` - so the `ř` isn't shown correctly but the long i `í` is. There are other characters for example `č` `ň` `ř` that are also not showing correctly.

After some investigation it looks like the file is in ASCII encoding (a subset of UTF-8).

```
 file ~/my_location/my_file.txt
 ~/my_location/my_file.txt: ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

I've checked the character set for ASCII and for example `ř` is present, so I'm wondering if the issue is that these characters are already corrupted or the above file encoding check that I used isn't showing the correct file encoding.

I've tried a few conversions to utf8 but none of them fix the characters.

```
 iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 ~/my_location/my_file.txt > ~/my_location/my_file_f_ISO-8859-1.txt
 iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 ~/my_location/my_file.txt > ~/my_location/my_file_f_CP1252.txt
 iconv -f Windows-1252 -t UTF-8 ~/my_location/my_file.txt > ~/my_location/my_file_f_Windows-1252.txt
```

Would appreciate if anyone has any thoughts on how I can proceed in the investigation...

Comment: Look at the file in a hex editor to see the actual bytes the characters consist of, then try to figure out any encoding that could encode that character using those bytes.

Comment: that's perfect thanks, all characters showing as `?` have the same underlying byte code which must mean that these characters are corrupted in the file, not an issue with displaying the file with the wrong encoding

Comment: BTW—í and ř aren't in the ASCII character set. It's actually quite rare that a file would be written with the ASCII encoding.

Comment: i was checking http://www.ascii-code.com/ I found `í` (355) but looking through again I can't find `ř` perhaps that is why it has been converted to `?`?